# Angular Interceptor - Refresh token before execute any request

Tags: angular, graphql, jwt, apollo-client

I have this implementation

```
intercept(
request: HttpRequest<any>,
next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

if (request.url.includes(environment.apiUrl)) {
  // Get the tokens from the storage
  const token = this.jwtService.getAccessToken();
  const refreshToken = this.jwtService.getRefreshToken();

  // Check if the request URL is excluded from authentication (e.g., login or refresh token API)
  if (this.isAuthExcluded(request)) {
    return next.handle(request);
  }

  //Check if access and refresh tokens are expired,
  //redirect user to login
  if (
    this.jwtService.isTokenExpired(token) &&
    this.jwtService.isTokenExpired(refreshToken)
  ) {
    this.authService.doLogout();
  }

  //Check if access token are expired, refresh token and continue with the request
  if (this.jwtService.isTokenExpired(token)) {
    if (!this.refreshTokenInProgress.value) {
      this.refreshTokenInProgress.next(true);
      return this.jwtService.refreshToken(refreshToken).pipe(
        concatMap((data) => {
          this.jwtService.saveTokens(data);
          request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `${data.accessToken}`,
            },
          });
          return next.handle(request);
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          this.authService.doLogout();
          return throwError(() => Error(error));
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.refreshTokenInProgress.next(false);
        })
      );
    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenInProgress.pipe(
        concatMap(() => next.handle(request))
      );
    }
  } else {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `${this.jwtService.getAccessToken()}`,
      },
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
return next.handle(request);}
```

My problem is that while the request to refresh the token is running, I keep processing the rest of the requests without the new token that I should receive in the response of the request to refresh the token

I need the request that is executed in the `this.jwtService.refreshToken(refreshToken)` to finish before I can continue with the rest of the request because I need to have the new token to add it in the headers of the rest.

I know about catching 401 status error but also I am using apollo-client and all my request has the status 200, so I'm checking before launching the request.

Comment: Even when using apollo client you can use the standard refresh token flow, there is already a lot of hints on the web, you can take a look at https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-refresh-token, it contains 3 ways to build an interceptor, I prefer the caughtInterceptor

Comment: But I always get status 200 in all my request using Apollo, In these examples, they are using the request status error 401 so I can't use the catchError